# Как упростить код с дублированием компонентов?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Пример абстрактный. Допустим на форме есть три checkBox. Если нажат первый, то переменная увеличивается на 1200, если нажат второй, то переменная увеличивается на 400, если на третий, то переменная увеличивается на 800.
Код

```
If (checkBox1.Checked)
    itog += 1200;
If (checkBox2.Checked)
    itog += 400;
If (checkBox3.Checked)
    itog += 800;
```

Как упростить такой код? Switch не воспользоваться, так как компоненты разные. Обращаться через Controls, тогда будет еще больше кода. Понятно одно, что такая реализация очень некрасивая, но сделать ее лучше у меня не получается. Надеюсь, что мне откроют глаза на то, как не дублировать код в данном и смежных случаях.

Comment: Такое решается через ООП, наследование, и прочее. Сейчас вы просто дергаете UI, который за что-то там отвечает, когда как должны отделить UI от логики, сделать конкретные объекты, со своим значением и т.д. Условно корзина магазина, сейчас у вас условно `checkBox1` - это молоко, `checkBox2` - банан, `checkBox3` - телевизор, все лежит в одной куче, когда как должна быть коллекция `public List<Item> Cart {get;} = new()`, в которую вы добавляет предметы (`Cart.Add(new("Банан", 100))`), дальше уже считаете общую сумму, например `var sum = Cart.Sum(x=>Price);` Ну а `Item` - это "описание" предмета.

Comment: Ну а сейчас, вы можете только писать что-то вроде `var values = new Dictionary<bool, int> { { checkBox1.Checked, 1200 }, { checkBox2.Checked, 400 }, { checkBox3.Checked, 800 } };`, а уже потом проходится по полученным значениям и делать что-то вроде `foreach (var value in values){ itog += value.Key ? value.Value : 0; }`, но зачем этот костыль, когда можно сразу делать как положено, верно?

Comment: Оставьте так как есть. Все эти паттерны, ооп, абстракции - от лукавого. Нет ничего лучше обычного if-else. Но всё должно быть в меру само собой

Comment: А какого типа `checkBox`? WPF, Unity, или это другой движок?

Answer (score 1):

можно что-то в таком духе написать:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int itog = 0;
    int cntAll = 0;
    int cntCheck = 0;
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        cntAll++;
        int i;
        if (c is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)c).Checked && int.TryParse(c.Tag?.ToString(), out i))
        {
            cntCheck++;
            itog += i;
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show(this, $"Всего контролов: {cntAll}, выбрано чекбоксов со значением: {cntCheck}, сумма выбранных значений: {itog}");
}
```

Идея в использовании специального поля Tag у чекбокса для хранения пользовательской информации (там может быть не только строка, а любой объект).

Значение поля Tag можно задавать в дизайнере.